# How to unsubscribe from an array of subscription

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-apollo

I have an array of `subscribeToMore` from Apollo query that I want to use. I was inspired by this [article](https://janikvonrotz.ch/2016/11/28/reactive-subscriptions-with-apollo-and-react/), expect I want to use a functional component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe =
        [subscribeToMore({
            // subscriptionData...
        }), subscribeToMore({
            // subscriptionData...
        })]


    if (unsubscribe.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < unsubscribe.length; i++) {
            return () => unsubscribe[i]()
        }
    }
}, [subscribeToMore])
```

However, I'm getting:

> In unsubscribe`[i]`(), unsubscribe[i] is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` just has one return function. You cannot call it multiple times. Instead inside the return function you can check for the condition and unsubscribe if there are subscriptions to be cleared

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe =
        [subscribeToMore({
            // subscriptionData...
        }), subscribeToMore({
            // subscriptionData...
        })]

    return () => {
       if (unsubscribe.length > 0) {
           for (i = 0; i < unsubscribe.length; i++) {
               unsubscribe[i]()
           }
       }
    }

}, [subscribeToMore])
```